# Get joint-frequency of two binned variables from pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe with two timeseries variables as follows:

| Temperature | Humidity |
| --- | --- |
| 17.6 | 88 |
| 22.1 | 81 |
| 13.6 | 88 |
| 26.4 | 71 |
| 25.6 | 72 |

Here is the `pd.DataFrame` for it:

```
data = {
    'Temperature': [17.6, 22.1, 13.6, 26.4, 25.6],
    'Humidity': [88, 81, 88, 71, 72]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to obtain a table, which has these two variables, binned as the axes, and the values being the frequency (nominal or relative) of the combined condition.

For example, the end output would be formatted with binned temperatures as columns and binned humidity as the index:

|  | 0-4 | 4-8 | 8-12 | 12-16 | 16-20 | 20-24 | 24-28 | 28-32 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0-10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10-20 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 20-30 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 30-40 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 40-50 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 50-60 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 60-70 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 70-80 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 80-90 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 90-100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I know how to bin and get the counts for one binning, but I'm really not sure how to count the combined occurrences of two binned conditions. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

```
df['T_binned'] = pd.cut(df['Temperature'],bins=np.arange(0,32,4))
df['H_binned'] = pd.cut(df['Humidity'],bins=np.arange(0,100,10))
counts_T = df.groupby(by='T_binned').count()
counts_H = df.groupby(by='H_binned').count()
```

Comment: I guess you can use a pivot table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df['Temperature'],bins=np.arange(0,32,4)),
            pd.cut(df['Humidity'],bins=np.arange(0,100,10)))
```

Or for all categories:

```
pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df['Temperature'],bins=np.arange(0,32,4)),
            pd.cut(df['Humidity'],bins=np.arange(0,100,10)),
            dropna=False
           )
```

Output:

```
Humidity     (0, 10]  (10, 20]  (20, 30]  (30, 40]  (40, 50]  (50, 60]  (60, 70]  (70, 80]  (80, 90]
Temperature                                                                                         
(0, 4]             0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
(4, 8]             0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
(8, 12]            0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
(12, 16]           0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1
(16, 20]           0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1
(20, 24]           0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1
(24, 28]           0         0         0         0         0         0         0         2         0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this works:

```
df['count'] = 1

df_group = df.groupby(['T_binned', 'H_binned'])['count'].sum().reset_index()

pd.pivot_table(df_group, index='T_binned', columns='H_binned', values='count')
```

First, we create a column for the count:

```
df['count'] = 1
```

Then we count the number in each pair of bin:

```
df_group = df.groupby(['T_binned', 'H_binned'])['count'].sum().reset_index()
```

Finally, we create a dataframe where the `index` is the temperature bin, `column` is the humidity bin and the `values` is the count in each bin.